# iphone flip between two view controllers in a tabbar

Tags: iphone

I have an application with a tabbar, and each controller inside a tabbar has a navigationbar. In one of the tabs, I would like to flip between the currently shown controller, and another viewcontroller. Tabbar and everything else has to remain as is. I don't want to use `pushViewController animated` because that would hide the tabbar. I've seen many examples with flipping the views inside the same view controller, but I just can get it right when it comes to flipping views of two different controllers.
I would like to know:
1) How to flip only the area between the navigation bar and the tabbar?
2) How to flip the entire controller including the navigation bar? (But leaving tabbar as is).

Answer (score 1):

I think the 2) is just presenting a view controller modally using a flip animation:

> viewController.modalTransitionStyle =
>   UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;

Answer (score 0):

Following code is use for the implementing the animation on the view for that you need to   Import QuartzCore.framework in your project.

```
CATransition *tr=[CATransition  animation];
tr.duration=0.75;
tr.timingFunction=[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
tr.type=kCATransitionPush;
tr.subtype=kCATransitionFromRight;
tr.delegate=self;
[self.window addSubview:self.nvCtr.view];
[self.nxtdSplashVCtr.view removeFromSuperview];
[self.window.layer addAnimation:tr forKey:nil];



 - For AnimationType you can use following option.

 1. kCATransitionMoveIn
 2. kCATransitionPush
 3. kCATransitionReveal
 4. kCATransitionFade


- For AnimationSubType you can use following option.

1. kCATransitionFromLeft
2. kCATransitionFromRight
3. kCATransitionFromTop
4. kCATransitionFromBottom
```

Comment: what is nvCtr? Navigation Controller?